# APNs AdHoc testing

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I know question like this must have been asked a lot.

**CASE-**
I codesign-ed my app on Distribution AdHoc provisioning profile. I have installed my Production Push SSL Certificate p12 on my server to push messages.

The messages are being pushed successfully from the server, but not received on the device.

Now after digging further I read that the devicetokens for the sandbox and gateway should be different. Makes sense if the device token returned by the APNs are dependent on the aps-environment string value. So, I did unregister the app from notifications.

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterFromRemoteNotifications];`

Executed the app with the code mention above implemented in. Then removed the code and registered the app with APNs again. Got it registered successfully, but the device token I received did not changed, it was the same.

From the server I pushed a message. And checked the console logs for the device. (I did sign the app with the AdHoc Distribution profile and checked the console logs). I received the following in the logs:-

`apsd[301] <APSCourier: 0x119f60>: Connecting courier stream using DNS TXT record at sandbox.push.apple.com and port TCP 5223`

`apsd[301] <Warning>: Fall back to alternate interface was disabled`

`apsd[301] <Warning>: Wake schedule completed for 2012-07-20 18:45:58 GMT (took 0.070 seconds)`

`apsd[301] <Warning>: Interface manager: Binding stream to WWAN context kCTDataConnectionServiceTypeInternet`

`apsd[301] <Warning>: <APSCourier: 0x119f60>: Connecting to courier 10-courier.sandbox.push.apple.com.`

All the messages sent from the server were logged in the console of the device but it never poped up. I guess the OS drops them.

Now the questions,

1. Why the tokens did not change?
2. Why the app when build on AdHoc Distribution provisioning profile tries to call sandbox.push.apple.com when it should have tried to gateway.push.apple.com ?
3. And why port 5223 when I was on 3G connection?
4. Why the push pop ups were not displayed?

I am dry of ideas, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app started behaving as expected after 24 hrs. I guess there is something like a batch process for updating tokens with the concerning servers of the APNs .